# After running solvePnP on the face of a cube with known dimensions, how do I get the camera coordinates of the vertices?

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, three.js, virtual-reality

We're trying to build a simple augmented reality application that uses OpenCV to detect and track a box from a camera and Three.js to render a 3D image of the box which we a user can pan and rotate the camera around. We're nearly there but after almost 2 weeks of reading stack overflow we're stuck at the last OpenCV step.

Here's what we've tried:

We have cube with sides that are 5 cm long. Using OpenCV's calibrate camera I've got the camera matrix. Next I ran solvePnP on the image coordinates of one of the cube's faces and the object coordinates of that face. These are the object coordinates for the face: [[0,0,0],[5,0,0],[0,5,0],[5,5,0]].

Now I have rvec and tvec for that cube face. Using this we ran [projectPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints) to get the pixel coordinates of the rest of the cube's vertices. Plotting this on an image is successful, so we're good up until this point.

Now we want to take the pixel coordinates for each vertex returned by projectPoints and get the camera coordinates. We think we've managed to translate the points correctly, but still cannot figure out how to rotate them.

We've tried every solution we can find, but I think we're misunderstanding the math or missing something trivial. Can someone point us to some sample code that performs this type of operation?

**EDIT in reply to Micka's comment:**

Here's the function we're using to try and apply the rotation matrix from Rodrigues(rvec) and tvec to each point in the cube (box_coordinates look like this [0,0,0],[5,0,0],[0,5,0]...):

```
def rotate_translate_point(point, rvecs, tvecs):
    rot_mat, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)
    point = np.dot(rot_mat, point)
    point = map(sum, zip(point, tvecs))  # translate by tvec
    return point

def rotate_box_and_translate(box_coordinates, rvecs, tvecs):
    return [rotate_translate_point(point, rvecs, tvecs) for point in box_coordinates]
```

Comment: not sure if I understood the problem, but to me it looks like you just have to convert rvec and tvec to a 4D homogenous transformation (see opencv rodriguez function for rvec) and multiply on your homogenous cube/object/whatever coordinates.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for the reply. We think we're trying this, but because we don't fully understand the math we may be doing something wrong. I've updated the question with the code we're using for this part, do you mind taking a look?

Comment: sorry, not sure about the python syntax.

Comment: It's basically taking rvecs and making it into a rotation matrix which is stored in rot_mat.  Then we take the dot product of rot_mat and point and add tvecs to it.  Does that sound like the right operations and order?

Comment: not 100% sure, it's some time since I did all that stuff, would be easier if you just compute 4x4 transformation matrices (3D space in homogenous coordinates).

Comment: can you post some sample rot_mat, point, tvecs, rotated point and translated rotated point?